# Java - Filling an ArrayList of Threads with loop

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

this question is probably pretty easy to answer but I just don't get it.
I reduced my problem until this little piece of code was left in order to find the "origin" of this problem:
I'm trying to fill an ArrayList of Threads with a loop.

```
public static int u=0;

public void test(){
    while (u <10) {
        synchronized(threadList){
            threadList.add(u, new Thread(){                
                @Override public void run(){                    
                    System.out.println("Thread at Index: " + u);                     
                } 
            });
        }
        u++;            
    }

    threadList.get(2).start();    
}
```

With the last line I wanted to test the loop above by starting the thread at Index '2'.
I'm expecting the console to show "Thread at Index: 2" but instead this is shown:
"Thread at Index: 10"
No matter which integer I write in the ".get(int)"-method, I receive the index '10'.

Why is that? And how to fix this?

The creation of the threads seems to work...so is the integer 'u' the problem?

I appreciate any kind of help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `u` is static, so you'll always get current value (`10` when your program runs). You're not saving the value you used when creating the Thread anywhere.

Comment: If your thread list is accessed from only one thread (the main thread?) You do not need to synchronize using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you reference `u` in your `run` method

```
@Override public void run(){                    
    System.out.println("Thread at Index: " + u);                     
}
```

The current value of `u` is retrieved. At the end of your loop and when the thread runs, that value is `10`.

Try the following

```
public static int u = 0;

public void test(){
    while (u <10) {
        synchronized(threadList){
            threadList.add(u, new Thread(){     
                int i = u;

                @Override public void run(){                    
                    System.out.println("Thread at Index: " + i);                     
                } 
            });
        }
        u++;            
    }

    threadList.get(2).start();    
}
```

In your anonymous `Thread` class, you're setting an instance field `i` to the value `u` has when the constructor is called and printing that value when the `run()` is executed.

You reference `u` in a context that hasn't been executed yet, a thread. When the `run()` method eventually gets called, the program will evaluate the variable `u`, but at that point in the execution of the program, its value will be 10.  If, instead, you do the above, the variable `i` will hold the value at that exact moment. This is because when new `Thread` gets started and executed, field initialization occurs and `u` is evaluated right away.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.
Yes, it works! Thank you!

But I don't really understand why it does work with "int i".
..is it because int u is static and defined outside the method and int i stays inside the method an can't be accessed from outside and therefore it has always a certain value while the loops runs?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Minor improvement for little Runnables like this - make the instance variables (i in this example) `final` for clarity and thread safety.

Comment: @user in this case, thread safety doesn't really apply because we're dealing with an anonymous class. Short of reflection, no other class could access the field.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis ahh, now I get it!
Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: I always worry (overmuch) about premature publishing (not the real term, but you know what I mean).  Final takes care of that.

Comment: @user949300 I see that a final declaration in this case is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how did you type all that so fast on your phone??

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (u <10) {
        synchronized(threadList){

            final int u_final = u;

            threadList.add(u, new Thread(){                
                @Override public void run(){                    
                    System.out.println("Thread at Index: " + u_final );
                } 
            });
        }
        u++;            
    }
```

with a `final` variable, it is clear what its value will be, since it'll never change.

Comment: Oh, I see..thanks!

So, if I am understanding everything right: 
Would it have been better if I had used a for-loop since it comes with a loop-variable (for example "int i = 0;") that stays inside this loop forever and changes its value only while the loop is running?

Comment: @MuSiCkiLL8or You wouldn't have been able to use the for loop index `i` in the Thread directly because it belongs to a different scope. Try it, it won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

have a try the two ways:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestThread5 {
    public static int u=0;
    public ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void test() throws InterruptedException{
        while (u <10) {
            synchronized(threadList){
                threadList.add(u, new Thread(){                
                    @Override public void run(){                    
                        System.out.println("Thread at Index: " + u);                     
                    } 
                });
            }
            u++;            
        }
        for ( u = 0; u < 10; u++) {
            Thread thread = threadList.get(u); 
            thread.start();
            thread.join();
        }
       // threadList.get(2).start();    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new TestThread5().test();
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestThread4 {
    public  int u=0;
    public ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void test() throws InterruptedException{
        while (u <10) {
            synchronized(threadList){
                threadList.add(u, new MyThread(u));
            }
            u++;            
        }
        for(Thread thread :threadList){
            thread.start();
            thread.join();
        }
       // ((Thread) threadList.get(2)).start();    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new TestThread4().test();
    }
}
class MyThread extends Thread{
    private int u;
    public MyThread(int u){
        this.u = u;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread at Index: " + u);  
    }

}
```