# Why do i have to synchronized an ArrayList of Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronized

So i need to create an ArrayList of Threads but according to

[Java - Filling an ArrayList of Threads with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412308/java-filling-an-arraylist-of-threads-with-loop)

it seems that i need to use the synchronized keyword, my question then is:

If im calling this only on the main thread why do i have to use the synchronized keyword? There are no others threads that could potentially do the same right?

```
ArrayList<Thread> t = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int i=0;i<love.size();i++){
    BTConnection cbtc = love.get(i).btc;
    if(cbtc!=null){
        Communicate temp = new Communicate(cbtc);
        Thread ttemp = new Thread(temp);
        ttemp.start();
        t.add(ttemp);   
    }
}
```

Moreover if right below the code i use:

```
for(int i=0;i<t.size();i++){
    t.get(i).join();
}
```

Does the for loop stop until the ith thread returns and then proceed to wait for the ith+1?

Comment: Your question is very well formatted and formulated. Kudos for that as I see it's your first question. Keep in mind though that the language tag is maybe the most important one so that users who follow the language tags they are proficient in can see your question emphasised.

Comment: You need some kind of synchronization if two or more threads may access and modify the same object concurrently. In your case, only the main thread knows about `t`, it's simply not visible from any of the created `Communicate` objects. You *might* need synchronization on those `BTConnection`s since those *can* be accessed by both the main thread and the created threads, but you'd have to be doing something really weird (why would you use one connection in multiple threads?) for that to actually become an issue.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Well, the connection should keep changing at each iteration of the loop... Am i wrong?

Comment: You don't need to sync here. If all you want is to wait for all threads to complete then look into using a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch. You would need to modify the thread code in Communicate to call latch.countDown() before returning.

Comment: @user217354 Yeah, there's no problem in your current code. I'm just saying that if you were to do something else with those connections later on (like spawn new threads doing something else with them), you might need to synchronize... Uh, forget about it already: your code is fine. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you would need to synchronize the threadlist, if only one thread is adding values into it/reading from it. As for the second part, you are correct, the `join`-call will block until the `i`'th thread has finished, before moving to wait for the next one.